# Single select property in Notion API

Tags: javascript, node.js, notion-api

How do I access single select options in using the JavaScript SDK for Notion API?

I tried the method of multi_select by WebDevSimplified, but it didn't work, don't know why.

Comment: I think there is a method called `page.properties` you could use that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.